# How to authenticate users in open layers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I need to authenticate users with PHP and MySQL, to connect to wms server, with OpenLayers 3 `tilewms` function.

I need write PHP Proxy between OpenLayers and wms server. I've tried proxy host but it is OpenLayers 2 function and is old.

How to i can implement that (AJAX, curl, etc.)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

alternatively i used squid proxy server with php/mysql plugin for authenticate users with socket proxy(tcp/ip)